# "по мірі того, як" чи існує український відповідник?

Tags: переклад, росіянізм, відповідник

"по мірі того, як" - це калька з російської.

Чи існує український відповідник для цієї фрази і якщо ніт, як краще здійснити переклад українською щоб звучало органічно? Дякую.

Comment: Наведіть, будь ласка, приклади речень.

Answer (score 2):

#### Замінники

- Олена Курило в «Уваги до сучасної української літературної мови» (1924; [§ 18 «Прийменники»](http://kurylo.wikidot.com/18-pryimennyky)) радить замінювати «по мірі того» на **«у(в) міру того»**. Цю пораду повторюють багато сайтів ([1](https://ukr-lifehacks.ed-era.com/rozdil-13/tipovi_pomilki), [2](https://zno.if.ua/?p=3398), [3](http://biblioteka-turgeneva.edu.kh.ua/internet-kejs_bibliotekarya/vivchayemo_ukrainsjku_movu/)). Приклад вжитку:

  > І в міру того, як хід його ставався повільніший, він чимраз глибше затоплювався в свої думки, чимраз тяжчі невдачі і страти наводив на Германа, упокорював того товстенького, спокійного, мов муром обведеного, багача, наводив на нього тривогу, аж вкінці - перед самим входом додому - обалив його зовсім і враз з його скаженою жінкою вигнав з посліднього закутка, з дому на бориславськім тракті. <…> В міру того, як Рифка відвикала від праці, праця ставалась їй чимраз ненависнішою і тяжчою; вона не могла пересилувати себе, щоб прочитати аби одну книжку, хоть перед кількома літами тітка навчила була її трохи читати (Іван Франко, «Борислав сміється», 1881).
- Ірина Фаріон у монографії «Мовна норма знищення пошук віднова» (2013, видання третє, ISBN 978-966-428-290-8; розділ [«Типові лексичні і граматичні помилки та їхні правильні відповідники»](http://emlab.ho.ua/Service----/Slovnyk_typovyh_pomylok_mod.html), с. 322) радить замінювати «по мірі того, як» на **«відповідно до того, як»**.

#### Чи непритаманна конструкція?

Утім я не впевнений, що конструкція «по мірі» (і зокрема «по мірі того, як» як частковий випадок) наскільки непритаманна українській мові, наскільки це подають. Її [вживали](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=phrase&keyword=%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%80%D1%96&refs=%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.authTrans%2C%3Ddoc.date&refs_up=1&sort=%5B%7B%22skey%22:%22kw%22,%22attr%22:%22doc.date%22,%22ctx%22:%220%22%7D%5D&showresults=1) Микола Устиянович, Олександр Шишацький-Ілліч, Михайло Драгоманов, Іван Франко, Михайло Старицький та інші. Приказку «добре все по мірі» наводить Матвій Номис у збірці «Українські приказки, прислів'я і таке інше» (1864; № 5860, [с. 113](https://archive.org/details/nomis1864/page/n125/mode/2up)).

Утім не можу не зазначити, що конструкцію «по мірі» вживали здебільшого в XIX сторіччі. З кінця XIX ст. починає домінувати «у(в) міру», і лише з настанням незалежності відбувається деяке збільшення частоти «по мірі»:
[image]
[image]

P.S.:

- Дані щодо вживання «по мірі» і «у(в) міру» — з Генерального регіонально анотованого корпусу (ГРАК) української мови версії 16.
- Ще зрідка вживають «у(в) мірі того, як» (замість «у(в) міру того, як»), але це відбувається настільки рідко, що радше схоже на авторський стиль чи описку.

Comment: Дякую за фантастичну відповідь. Контексту не маю, я перекладачка, тому просто потребувала варіант, який би звучав більш автентично.